# How to prove that homology is a functor?

Tags: category-theory, definition, homology-cohomology

Is a homology operator $H_k:(cKom) \rightarrow (Ab)$ a functor?

I know this is a really simple question, but I'm not familiar with category theory and do not know how to prove this... (I'm even not sure if I've stated the question clear.) Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is cKom?  The category of chain complexes of modules over some ring?

Answer (score 2):

By definition a homology operator is a functor. This only refers to the very basics of definitions in category theory. All it says is that if $id$ is an identity morphism in $cKom$ (whatever $cKom$ may be in your case), then $H_k(id)$ is an identity morhpism in $Ab$, and that if $f:X\to Y $ and $g:Y\to Z$ are morphisms in $cKom$, then $H_k(g\circ f)=H_k(f)\circ H_k(g)$. You prove these identities based on the particular homology construction you have at hand.

Comment: Thank you! But now I can ask it more clearly.. the object in $(Ab)$ are quotient groups, so what does the function $H_k(f)$ looks like (where $f$ is from an object in $(cKom)$ to an object in $(Ab)$)?

Comment: $Ab$ is the category of abelian groups. Its objects are abelian groups. The homology construction associates a certain quotient group with every object of $cKom$.